# how to save a screenshot (matlab)

Tags: java, matlab, save, screenshot

I am trying to save a screenshot in a specific directory using Matlab. I am able to generate the screenshot but I find no solution to save it in a specific directory. I have tried save and saveas but get error messages...Any ideas? Really appreciate any help.

```
robo = java.awt.Robot;
t = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
rectangle = java.awt.Rectangle(t.getScreenSize());
image = robo.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
filehandle = java.io.File(sprintf('%s_screencapture.jpg',current_stock));

javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(image,'jpg',filehandle);

dest_dir = 'D:\screenshot\';
```

Comment: What are the error messages you get?

Comment: Many thanks. For the solutions I tried I get: Error using fullfile (line 93)
All inputs must be strings or cell arrays of strings.

Error in Chart_screenshots (line 22)
save (fullfile(dest_dir, filehandle));

Comment: Did not try, but how about this: save ([dest_dir, filehandle],'image')

Answer (score 3):

Does this work for you?

```
filepath = fullfile(dest_dir, sprintf('%s_screencapture.jpg',current_stock));

filehandle = java.io.File(filepath);

javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(image,'jpg',filehandle);
```

PS - best not to use `image` or `rectangle` as variable names, as they are the names of built-in MATLAB commands.

Comment: +1 Just the warning about variable names is worth it already!