# Capturing browser as videostream or image in matlab

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, screenshot

I am trying to make a Duck Hunt (http://www.thepcmanwebsite.com/media/duck_hunt/) bot in matlab.

I already have quite the idea of how to process images or video streams once I have them (http://www.mathworks.nl/help/vision/gs/object-detection-and-tracking.html), my problem is the acquisition.

How do I capture my browser as a video stream or as a series of single images(screenshots)? With 'getframe' I can do as much as capture figures etc, but not anything outside matlab as I understand it? Might it somehow be possible to automatically open my browser on a certain url and give it a handle or sth like that so getframe can handle it?

Thanks in advance, mind_

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [Get and save a screenshot with matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18186400/how-to-save-a-screenshot-matlab)

Comment: Not exactly, but it helped me get onto the right path, thanks :)